# WPF Context Menu for each Row in a GridView

Tags: wpf, templates, gridview, mvvm, contextmenu

I have a GridView which is has several columns which are all bound to a data structure in my ViewModel layer, so what I want to do is to

1. Have a Context Menu that will pop up when the user clicks on one of the rows of data in the GridView (so far I have only been able to make the context menu appear when I click on the Header of the column I put it on.
2. Have the contents of the context menu vary depending on the contents of the current row the user has clicked on.

Any suggestions? thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can set up the `ContextMenu` in the [`ItemContainerStyle`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemcontainerstyle.aspx), to make it dependent on the row you could employ some [`DataTriggers`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.datatrigger.aspx).

---

Edit: Structure should take the following form if you decide to swap out the whole ContextMenu on a condition:

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type ListViewItem}">
     <Style.Resources>
          <ContextMenu x:Key="DefaultMenu">
               <!-- Rest of menu here -->
          </ContextMenu>
          <ContextMenu x:Key="NonDefaultMenu">
               <!-- Rest of menu here -->
          </ContextMenu>
     </Style.Resources>
     <Style.Triggers>
         <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding SomeProperty}" Value="SomeValue">
             <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource NonDefaultMenu}"/>
         </DataTrigger>
     </Style.Triggers>
     <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource DefaultMenu}"/>
</Style>
```

---

You normally could also define the ContextMenu in place as well but if you add event-handlers it gets buggy, the syntax would be:

```
 <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
      <Setter.Value>
          <ContextMenu>
              <!-- Rest of menu here -->
          </ContextMenu>
      </Setter.Value>
 </Setter>
```

Comment: I'm trying to add a DataTrigger in the Style.Triggers section and inside of the DataTrigger I have a Context Menu but I'm still getting the error "A value of type 'Context Menu' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection', sorry my first time programming in WPF so i have no idea what this means, am i missing something?

Comment: Added some example code (which hopefully isn't wrong too as i wrote it right here)...

Comment: @H.B., that error "A value of type 'Context Menu' cannot be added to a collection or dictionary of type 'SetterBaseCollection'" will go away if we create a StaticResource of the Context menu and set that as a value.... <Setter Property="ContextMenu" Value="{StaticResource ContextMenuForThisCondition}">